# Flex 3 debugging not working with FIREFOX 3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Flex 3 debugging not working with FIREFOX 3 (under vista)

no trace() shown in console.  breakpoints not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Do you have Flex Builder installed? If not, if you are using the free SDK, did you install the debug version of the Flash player?</s>

Try reinstalling the debug version of the Flash player. [Here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)'s a link, in case you didn't. I had the same problem a week back -- corrupted my install. But also check out the config files as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: flex builder 3,   and flash cs4.

Answer (score 1):

It worked perfect after installing the debugger from the link given above.
The exe that should be installed is listed as "Download the Windows Flash Player 10.1 ActiveX control content debugger (for IE) (EXE, 2.72 MB) " in http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have:

```
ErrorReportingEnable=1
TraceOutputFileEnable=1
```

In a file called `mm.cfg` in your home directory?  I'm using FF3 on Windows Server 2k3 and it works fine, so I can't speak to why it wouldn't work on Vista.  Despite Vista's reputation for being broken, I doubt that this is a Vista-only problem you're experiencing.  You're sure you've got the debugging flash player installed?